# Is the Performance issue with TPT inheritance fixed in EF6?

Tags: entity-framework, inheritance, entity-framework-6, table-per-type

In earlier versions of Entity Framework there were some serious performance concerns when using Table per Type inheritance as documented here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/66313/The-Entity-Framework-v1-and-v4-Deal-Breaker-TPT-In#xx4798195xx

or here : http://samscode.com/index.php/2010/01/the-entity-framework-v1-and-v4-deal-breaker-tpt-inheritance/

The issue being that the framework spends a very long time building up huge ugly SQL statements (which then can also take a long time to actually run).

I understand that there is an implicit performance hit with TPT as the tables must be joined, but I have heard it noted that other ORM solutions handle this significantly better than EF4.

To what degree is this performance problem still a serious issue in EF6.1?

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is going back some, but I'm on EF 6.1.3 and still experience this problem.

So, no, it's not been fixed.

I do not know about later versions of EF though.

Comment: Still an issue with Entity Framework 6.2.0 here. Both query generation and execution time scales very poorly with the number of subclasses and includes.